# YouTube Data API stopped returning results after server change

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I recently moved a website to a different server, and most things are back to normal with the exception of the YouTube API.

The API still returns results on the old server, but on the new server it returned the following error

```
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [domain] => usageLimits
                            [reason] => keyInvalid
                            [message] => Bad Request
                        )

                )

            [code] => 400
            [message] => Bad Request
        )

)
```

Initially I thought the obvious thing, that it was only authorised on my old server ip address. But even after adding the ip address of the new server, and even creating a new server key, I still cannot get rid of this error